# My state remains the same despite running through reducer. Shouldn't happen

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am doing everything by the letter, but the redux-devtools does not show any diff in my state. My code

```
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import { storeLogger } from 'ngrx-store-logger';

import {
  ActionReducerMap,
  createSelector,
  createFeatureSelector,
  ActionReducer,
  MetaReducer,
} from '@ngrx/store';

import { ResultInteface } from '../models/results';
import * as search from '../actions/search';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export interface SearchState {
  queryString: string;
  messages: string[];
  results: ResultInteface[];
  loading: boolean;
}

export interface State {
  search: SearchState;
}

export const intialState: SearchState = {
  queryString: '',
  messages: [],
  results: [],
  loading: false
};

export function searchReducers(state = intialState, action: search.Actions): SearchState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case search.SEARCH_COUNTRY:
      state.queryString = action.payload;
      return state;
    case search.SEARCH_COUNTRY_ISO2:
      return state;
    case search.SEARCH_COUNTRY_ISO3:
      return state;
    case search.SEARCH_COUNTRY_COMPLETE:
      state.messages = action.payload.RestResponse.messages;
      state.results = action.payload.RestResponse.result;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  search: searchReducers
};

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): any {
  return storeLogger()(reducer);
}


export const getResults = (state: SearchState) => state.results;
export const getSearchState = createFeatureSelector<SearchState>('search');
export const getSearchResults = createSelector(
  getSearchState,
  getResults
);
```

Comment: can we see the form code?

Comment: How are you dispatching the actions?

Comment: i solved the problem .. the problem was with ```case search.SEARCH_COUNTRY_COMPLETE:``` case .. i needed to first shallow clone my state to assign properties to it.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler and artSir .. thankyou for prompt reply.